# how to view excel and powerpoint documents directly in zendesk help center articles

Tags: excel, powerpoint, zendesk

Zendesk allows you to upload both excel and powerpoint files to help center articles, but it does not allow you to view them within the article. Instead, users have to download the file to view it.

I am looking for a solution to be able to upload excel and powerpoint files to a help center article and be able to view the content of the file in the article.

Comment: It might help if you mentioned what file types Zendesk *does* allow you to view from within the article, if any.

Comment: Unfortunately Zendesk do not let you view any file types within the article - unless they are embedded through code